# Heroku fails with `error reading plugin: heroku-local`

Tags: heroku

```
heroku git:clone -a damp-rando-1234
Installing Heroku Toolbelt v4... done
heroku-cli: Installing core plugins.../home/amanda/.heroku/node_modules/heroku-local/commands/run.js:17
  process.argv.push(...context.args);
                    ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/amanda/.heroku/node_modules/heroku-local/index.js:8:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
heroku-cli: Installing core plugins (retrying).../home/amanda/.heroku/node_modules/heroku-local/commands/run.js:17
  process.argv.push(...context.args);
                    ^^^
```

It repeats everything from Syntax Error on four times and then exits with

```
 ▸    Error reading plugin: heroku-local
 ▸    exit status 1
```

I tried removing and reinstalling Heroku, but I'm getting the same error.

I'm guessing those carets are trying to tell me something about where the problem lies but I'm stumped.

There are a handful of questions here that seem similar but all were resolved either by destroying `~/.heroku` or reinstalling. And neither has worked for me. I'm on Ubuntu Wily.

Note: Heroku support asked me to give them the output of ``GODE_DEBUG=info heroku update`

Comment: Konstantin Zolotarev's answer worked for me. Perhaps you could post up what happens after you deleted the ~/.heroku folder? And I assume when you say you reinstall, you're reinstalling the latest?

Comment: I installed by manually following the install steps at https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh -- added the repository to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/heroku.list` and then used `apt-get` to install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that new version is not comparable with old one. 
I also had same problem. Solved by removing `~/.heroku` folder

Comment: I'm so frustrated. I removed `heroku-toolbelt` with `apt` and confirmed that that also removed `~/.heroku`. But indeed, removing the folder *again* seems to have cleared things up. Makes no sense but works.